# Java - Gherkin & Cucumber : Pass Object with arrayList of objects

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

i have the following java model :

```
public class User {

  private String name;

  private String password;


  private List<Comment> commentsList;
  
}


public class Comment {

  private Long id;
  private String description;

}
```

i want to know how i can write my gherkin data for a user with 2 comments object as a datatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
Scenario: User with 2 comments
Given I have a User
  | name | password |
  | John | pass     |
And users have the following comments
  | id | description |
  | 1  | first       |
  | 2  | second      |
```

With Step definition sample as

```
    User user;

    @Given("I have a User")
    public void iHaveAUser(Map<String, String> userData) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userData.get("name"));
        user.setPassword(userData.get("password"));
        List<Comment> commentsList = new ArrayList<>();
        user.setCommentsList(commentsList);
        this.user = user;
        // Save the user object for later use
    }

    @And("users have the following comments")
    public void usersHaveTheFollowingComments(List<Map<String, String>> commentsData) {

        List<Comment> commentsList = this.user.getCommentsList();
        // Map the datatable to Comment objects and add them to the list
        for (Map<String, String> commentData : commentsData) {
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            comment.setId(Long.valueOf(commentData.get("id")));
            comment.setDescription(commentData.get("description"));
            commentsList.add(comment);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works but i just passed List<Comment> commentsList and User user as a method parameters